# SlickGrid (autoHeight:true) with paging

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I'm using SlickGrid and what I'm trying to do is display a my grid without a vertical scrollbar, but with paging still functional.

When I use the option `autoHeight:true`, the vertical scroll bar is removed but paging is broken. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`autoHeight:true` and `paging` are incompatible.

If I understand your issue correctly, you want to render, say, 25 rows at a time on a given page, but your grid is too small to render the 25 rows on that page, so a vertical scrollbar appears on the right and you want to get rid of it.

To do so, you should set the height attribute of your grid div to a value that allows you to see exactly the 25 rows that are shown on a given page. For instance:

```
<div id="myGrid" style="height:800px;"></div>
```